# form validation message inside textbox

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

How to make validation something like this screen shot..!

is there any jquery plugin ,will do the validation...

[my screebshot](http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/966/loginh.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best one out there is JQuery Validate to be found [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate)
More info also on [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: you will need to make some changes to the plugin, the plugin will create a <label class="error"> to display every error message.

Comment: yes that is possible too. it would a combination of watermarking and validation.

Comment: this one little bit what i expected